# how to make a generic method for a list iteration C#

Tags: c#

in my c# I am looping through a list of XML `XElement` everytime I am going to write same code for other list, only because Class Type is different and some list has different nodes names
here is my code, how do I make this generic to re use same functionality for all my list

```
if (listType == "A")
{
    var lstIndividuals = e.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == parentNodeForPerson);

    Data _individualData;
    List<Data> individualList = new List<Data>();

    //here need some generic function to call below functionality
    foreach (var individual in lstIndividuals)
    {
        _individualData = new Data();
        _individualData.First_Name 
            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).Any() == true 
            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).First().Value : "";
        _individualData.Last_Name 
            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).Any() == true 
            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).First().Value : "";                       

        var lstIndvidualAlias = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == childNodeForPerson);
        _individualData.Alias_Names = new List<Alias>();

        foreach (var alias in lstIndvidualAlias)
        {
            _individualData.Alias_Names
                .Add(new Alias()
                {
                    FirstName = alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).Any() == true
                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).First().Value : "",
                    LastName = alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).Any() == true
                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).First().Value : ""

                });
        }
        individualList.Add(_individualData);

    }


//also needs to check, if child does not exist
    var lstEntity = e.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == parentNodeForEntity);
    Data _entityData;
    List<DataEntity> entityList = new List<DataEntity>();
    foreach (var entity in lstEntity)
    {
        _entityData = new Data();
        _entityData.First_Name
            = entity.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityParentValue1).Any() == true
            ? entity.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityParentValue1).First().Value : "";
        _entityData.Last_Name
            = entity.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityParentValue2).Any() == true
            ? entity.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityParentValue2).First().Value : "";

        var lstEntityAlias = entity.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == childNodeForEntity);
        _entityData.Alias_Names = new List<Alias>();

        foreach (var alias in lstEntityAlias)
        {

                _entityData.Alias_Names.Add(new Alias(){
                    FirstName= alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityChildValue1).Any() == true
                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityChildValue1).First().Value : "",
                    LastName = alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityChildValue2).Any() == true
                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == entityChildValue2).First().Value : ""

                });


        }
        entityList.Add(_entityData);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(individualList);
    Console.WriteLine(entityList);
}
else if (listType == "B")
{                                                          
    var lstIndividuals = e.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == parentNodeForPerson); //nodes can be different
    Data _individualData;

    List<DataForB> individualList = new List<DataForB>(); //class type type of list is different

    foreach (var individual in lstIndividuals)
    {
        _individualData = new Data();
        _individualData.First_Name 
            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).Any() == true 
            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).First().Value : "";
        _individualData.Last_Name 
            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).Any() == true 
            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).First().Value : "";

        var lstIndvidualAlias = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == childNodeForPerson);
        _individualData.Alias_Names = new List<Alias>();

        foreach (var alias in lstIndvidualAlias)
        {

                _individualData.Alias_Names.Add(new Alias(){
                    FirstName =alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).Any() == true 
                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).First().Value : "",
                LastName = alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).Any() == true 
                ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).First().Value : ""
                });

        }
        individualList.Add(_individualData);

    }

    Console.WriteLine(individualList);

}
else if (listType == "C")
{
 //this type also repeat the same
}
else if (listType == "D")
{
//this type also repeat the same
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

I tried to create a methods which takes `list`, `nodes[]` and `classType<T>` as parameters but I could not understand how to handle the these inside code

**My Raw Try:**

```
public static List<XElement> DataMaping(object list, string[,] nodes, type<T>)
        {
            List<XElement> obj = new List<XElement>();

            foreach (var individual in list)
            {
                individualData = new Data(); //how this Data or some other class will be instantiated here
                        _individualData.First_Name 
                            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).Any() == true 
                            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue1).First().Value : "";
                        _individualData.Last_Name 
                            = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).Any() == true 
                            ? individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personParentValue2).First().Value : "";

                        var lstIndvidualAlias = individual.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == childNodeForPerson);
                        _individualData.Alias_Names = new List<Alias>();

                        foreach (var alias in lstIndvidualAlias)
                        {

                                _individualData.Alias_Names.Add(new Alias(){
                                    FirstName =alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).Any() == true 
                                    ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue1).First().Value : "",
                                LastName = alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).Any() == true 
                                ? alias.Descendants().Where(c => c.Name.LocalName.ToString() == personChildValue2).First().Value : ""
                                });

                        }
                        individualList.Add(_individualData);
            }

            return obj;
        }
```

Comment: Show method declartion, so we can know what you want to make generic. From what you said you can declare it as MyMethod<T>(Enumerable<T> source) where T : XElement

Comment: Well, I had just declare the normal method, not identical as you suggested

Comment: @EugeneGorbovoy updated question, I don't think it will help you, because I don't have idea to handle this types in generic fictions

Comment: So you can do public static List<XElement> DataMaping<TElement>(IEnumerable<TElement> list, string[,] nodes) where TElement : XElement may be ?